# Insert an entry into HKCU for each user account on a PC

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

I'm an admin charged with installing software to a small LAN of PCs.  The software had to be installed in separate stages (three different executable setup packages).

The sales muppets supplied the stages in the wrong order, and since they were installed in the wrong order, registry keys weren't correctly generated.

So I need to make an HKCU entry in the registry for each existing user on each PC.

The registry key I need to install is

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\AcmeSoft\AcmeApp]
"InstallLocation"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\AcmeApp"
@=""
```

I'd like to write a script (language is unimportant, I'm familiar with C++ and python though) that I can run once per PC to deploy this new registry key to the HKCU\Software\AcmeSoft\AcmeApp hive.

Regedit shows a hive called HKEY_USERS, which I suspect may contain entries for all users on the PC.

Can I somehow iterate HKEY_USERS and check for the aforementioned key and install it if its missing?
Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to use a logon script, or if you can't do that, get each user to manually import the necessary registry settings.  HKEY_USERS only contains the hives for users who are actually logged in.

Comment: Thanks Harry, I found that out the hard way :)  A login script is how I'll get this one done!  Thanks!

Comment: It's possible to do this without a login script.  You just need to load the NTUSER.DAT hive from the default profile and any already existing profiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not against using a simple batch script, you can use this:

You can even add a computername before HKU (like so: \Computer\HKU) if you like so you can run it remotely. You have to run it as admin (elevated)

```
for /F  "delims=\ tokens=1,*" %%t in ('reg query HKU') do reg add HKU\%%u\Software\AcmeSoft\AcmeApp /ve
for /F  "delims=\ tokens=1,*" %%t in ('reg query HKU') do reg add HKU\%%u\Software\AcmeSoft\AcmeApp /v InstallLocation /d C:\\Program Files (x86)\\AcmeApp
```

Comment: thanks rene, something else has come up, but I'll look into this soon, looks like just what I need.  Thanks!

Comment: apart from a minor syntax error, this almost solves my problem.

Comment: HKU is only users currently logged on.  This won't change anything for existing users that aren't logged on.

Answer (score 1):

I found a couple of simple syntax errors in the supplied answer.  Here's the correct syntax for those who may need it.

```
for /F  "delims=\ tokens=2,*" %t in ('reg query HKU') do 
    reg add HKU\%t\Software\AcmeSoft\AcmeApp /ve

for /F  "delims=\ tokens=2,*" %t in ('reg query HKU') do 
    reg add HKU\%t\Software\AcmeSoft\AcmeApp /v InstallLocation /d C:\\Program Files (x86)\\AcmeApp
```

But this isn't quite right.  Here's a list of entries in HKU:

[image: HKU hive]

The only one that appears to be a valid account in the system is:
S-1-5-21-856089149-4157031032-549160387-500

However, there are a lot of users that sign into this machine.

[image: user accounts on the PC]

So I need an alternative.  If I get it, I'll post it here.

**Update**
I found a command that lists all users, but this appears to query the domain controller for the information, which returns all accounts on the system (including admins, templates, inactive e.g. disabled accounts etc.)

```
wmic useraccount get name,sid
```

Useful to know, but overkill for my purposes.